# Yii2-User не приходит confirm-ссылка

Tags: yii2, email

После регистрации на сайте на локальном сервере `OpenServer` пришло в `runtime` такое письмо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем нет ссылки подтверждения почты, как быть?

Мой `web.php`

```
...
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'enableConfirmation' => true,
        ],
    ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение проблемы. Мб у кого-то будет такая же)

Нужно удалить папку `mail` из `app\views\user`. Тогда сообщение станет стандартным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]